# http post & get is blocking call?

Tags: c++, http, post, curl, blocking

I see most http codes in php.

I'm about to write some http calls in c++ using CURL.
Wonder if http is inherently blocking(opposed to non-blocking).
IE, when you send get/post message, your thread is blocked until it gets the response?

If it's not, is there a way to perform non-blocking http get or post with CURL?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP is a protocol, so it's not inherently blocking or non-blocking. The only thing resembling 'blocking behavior' in HTTP is that you can't send two requests or two responses at once in the same pipeline - you have to wait for the request to finish before sending another one.

So your real question about blocking operations should be about CURL - does it allow non-blocking IO?

The answer is that libcurl has something called the 'multi interface', which enables you to use it without blocking:
http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-multi.html

If you prefer a library that's better designed towards asynchronous IO, you can check out Boost.ASIO. I've never used it myself, but it seems to be popular:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_asio.html

Comment: @Daniel: Not at all. CURL was designed to be using primarily for synchronous access. I don't think the asynchronous features even existed in its earlier versions. That's not to say CURL is crappy, but it's obvious that Boost.ASIO was designed for Asynchronous IO (even the name says that), while CURL wasn't.